# toggleClass onClick - One div at a time

Tags: jquery, onclick

I am learning and in need of some help. I have two hidden boxes that become visible on button click. But, what I want is only one of them to be open at a time.

So, if **Box 1** is open

*Clicks Button to open Box 2* = **Box 1 Closes** and **Box 2 Opens**

```js
$("button").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).siblings(".box").toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px; height: 50px; background: red;
  display: none;
}

.box.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col">
  <button class="toggle-good">Show the box</button>
  <p class="box good"></p>
</div>
<div>Push me</div>

<div class="col">
  <button class="toggle-good">Show the box</button>
  <p class="box good"></p>
</div>
<div>Push me</div>
```

Comment: We really didn't need to see 95% of that CSS in order to understand and answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce a new `currentBox` variable and set it to (surprise!) the current box, and then `$(".box.active").not(currentBox).removeClass("active");` would remove the class and hide all of the boxes except for that one. So :

```js
$("button").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var currentBox = $(this).siblings(".box").toggleClass("active");
  $(".box.active").not(currentBox).removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px; height: 50px; background: red;
  display: none;
}

.box.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col">
  <button class="toggle-good">Show the box</button>
  <p class="box good"></p>
</div>
<div>Push me</div>

<div class="col">
  <button class="toggle-good">Show the box</button>
  <p class="box good"></p>
</div>
<div>Push me</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, nnnnnn. I do have one more question. I want to place the button outside class="col" and still make it work, how would one do that? Like <div class="col-wrap"> <!-- Button Here --> <div class="col"> <!-- Box Here -->

Comment: It'd be something like `$(this).next().find(".box").toggleClass("active")` or `$(this).parent().find(".box").toggleClass("active")` or basically whatever combination of [DOM tree traversal methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) makes sense to you to get from the button (`$(this)`) to the box div. You shouldn't need to change the line that hides the other boxes because it selected them directly.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the active class from all of the siblings and toggle the `active`class to your current button.

```
$("button").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().siblings().find(".box").removeClass("active‌​");
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Note that each button is sibling to only one box so your code would remove the class from the current button's box and then toggle it back on again. But you could do something like `$(this).parent().siblings().find(".box").removeClass("active")`.

Comment: Good catch, my answer has been updated with your suggestion @nnnnnn